# javascript/amcharts - easy way to use legend to show/hide columns of 1 graph for Amchart Column Chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I can't seem to find an easy way to add legend which has switchable functionality for items in a **single** graph for amcharts. I searched around and found a column chart which has switchable graphs ([JSFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/Cww3D/)). I found switchable items legend but it doesn't resize properly ([JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/g254sdq5/1/)).

This is the closest I can find to adding legends from multiple items of single graph ([CodePen 1](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/ac7232c4e81a518fa8a241630033d84e)). It is from amchart website itself but there is no switchable functionality. How can I add the switchable functionality here which allows column resizing (ie. 2 items will be shown with bigger column than 10 columns)? I tried this initially to just see if switch functionality can be added but it does not work:

```
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {
  //check if legend is enabled and custom generateFromData property
  //is set before running
  if (!chart.legend || !chart.legend.enabled || !chart.legend.generateFromData) {
    return;
  }

  var categoryField = chart.categoryField;
  var colorField = chart.graphs[0].lineColorField || chart.graphs[0].fillColorsField;
  var legendData =  chart.dataProvider.map(function(data) {
    var markerData = {
      "title": data[categoryField] + ": " + data[chart.graphs[0].valueField], 
      "color": data[colorField]
    };
    if (!markerData.color) {
      markerData.color = chart.graphs[0].lineColor;
    }
    return markerData;
  });

  chart.legend.data = legendData;

  // here is the code I add
  chart.legend.switchable=true;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** - The [AmCharts knowledge base demo](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/generate-legend-markers-column/) has been updated to include the modifications below.

In order to resize the chart outright, you have to actually modify the `dataProvider` and remove the element from the array and redraw the chart. You can use the legend's [`clickMarker`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#clickMarker) to store the data item into the event dataItem object and retrieve it as needed through the hidden flag. Combining the fiddles from previous solutions together, I came up with this:

```
/*
  Plugin to generate legend markers based on category
  and fillColor/lineColor field from the chart data by using 
  the legend's custom data array. Also allows for toggling markers
  and completely removing/adding columns from the chart

  The plugin assumes there is  only one graph object. 
*/
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) { 

  //method to handle removing/adding columns when the marker is toggled
  function handleCustomMarkerToggle(legendEvent) {
      var dataProvider = legendEvent.chart.dataProvider;
      var itemIndex; //store the location of the removed item

      //Set a custom flag so that the dataUpdated event doesn't fire infinitely, in case you have
      //a dataUpdated event of your own
      legendEvent.chart.toggleLegend = true; 
      // The following toggles the markers on and off.
      // The only way to "hide" a column and reserved space on the axis is to remove it
      // completely from the dataProvider. You'll want to use the hidden flag as a means
      // to store/retrieve the object as needed and then sort it back to its original location
      // on the chart using the dataIdx property in the init handler
      if (undefined !== legendEvent.dataItem.hidden && legendEvent.dataItem.hidden) {
        legendEvent.dataItem.hidden = false;
        dataProvider.push(legendEvent.dataItem.storedObj);
        legendEvent.dataItem.storedObj = undefined;
        //re-sort the array by dataIdx so it comes back in the right order.
        dataProvider.sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
          return lhs.dataIdx - rhs.dataIdx;
        });
      } else {
        // toggle the marker off
        legendEvent.dataItem.hidden = true;
        //get the index of the data item from the data provider, using the 
        //dataIdx property.
        for (var i = 0; i < dataProvider.length; ++i) { 
          if (dataProvider[i].dataIdx === legendEvent.dataItem.dataIdx) {
            itemIndex = i;
            break;
          }
        }
        //store the object into the dataItem
        legendEvent.dataItem.storedObj = dataProvider[itemIndex];
        //remove it
        dataProvider.splice(itemIndex, 1);
      }
      legendEvent.chart.validateData(); //redraw the chart
  }

  //check if legend is enabled and custom generateFromData property
  //is set before running
  if (!chart.legend || !chart.legend.enabled || !chart.legend.generateFromData) {
    return;
  }

  var categoryField = chart.categoryField;
  var colorField = chart.graphs[0].lineColorField || chart.graphs[0].fillColorsField;
  var legendData =  chart.dataProvider.map(function(data, idx) {
    var markerData = {
      "title": data[categoryField] + ": " + data[chart.graphs[0].valueField], 
      "color": data[colorField],
      "dataIdx": idx
    };
    if (!markerData.color) {
      markerData.color = chart.graphs[0].lineColor;
    }
    data.dataIdx = idx;
    return markerData;
  });

  chart.legend.data = legendData;

  //make the markers toggleable
  chart.legend.switchable = true;
  chart.legend.addListener("clickMarker", handleCustomMarkerToggle);

}, ["serial"]);
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/4aa2217adf80fc070c36716229e56c3c?editors=0010)

Comment: Thanks A LOT!! I haven't put your solution in my actual code but the demo on codepen looks perfect! Works exactly as I expect.

Comment: Thanks for the code and demo link. It really saved a lot of my time. The only thing, the UI needs to be adjusted so as to have the animation as we can see when in a normal column series we use `legend.itemContainers.template.togglable = true;`. I have more than one charts in a page (their number is dynamic), and trying to have a more consistent feel from animation point.

Comment: @Mahesh `legend.itemContainers.template.togglable = true;` is for AmCharts v4, and this is an answer for v3. If you have problems with v4, ask a separate question instead of commenting on an answer written years before v4's release.

Comment: @xorspark, sorry but I was unaware of the AmCharts version in the above code. Yes, I am looking for a solution with version 4. Will create a new question for the same