# Adding toggleable legend for AmCharts simple column chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

For adding legend markers for each column for AmCharts I followed this guide: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/generate-legend-markers-column/

This works, but what this guide is not providing is an ability to click on each legend item to toggle column in the chart. Is this option possible and if it is, how it is implemented?

Comment: Yes. This has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46701036/javascript-amcharts-easy-way-to-use-legend-to-show-hide-columns-of-1-graph-for).

Comment: I have also updated the knowledge base example to include this functionality from my answer to that question.