# With Amcharts 4, looking for a solution to show hide columns in bar charts where each legend represents a column

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

Is there a way to hide / show columns in a bar chart by clicking on legends ? Specifically, when each legend represents a column in the bar chart, as shown in [the example here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/individual-legend-item-for-each-column/).

There is custom solution found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46701036/javascript-amcharts-easy-way-to-use-legend-to-show-hide-columns-of-1-graph-for), and is a very good start. 
But this is with **AmCharts v3** and I am looking for AmCharts v4 with an approach where -

- can use property `legend.itemContainers.template.togglable`.
- any adapter to be implemented through known API

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

(***NOTE*** - The solution was provided by [zeroin](https://github.com/zeroin). I am merely quoting in here, so to be helpful for someone who requires this behaviour in AmCharts 4)

Here is the link with the complete solution - https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/bGNyXod

Basically, subscribing for the event `dataitemsvalidated` and `toggled` (on `legend.itemContainers`) did the work.

Relevant code snippet -

```
series.events.on("dataitemsvalidated", function(){
  var data = [];
  series.dataItems.each(function(dataItem){
    data.push({name:dataItem.categoryX, fill:dataItem.column.fill, dataItem:dataItem});
  })
  legend.data = data;
})

legend.itemContainers.template.events.on("toggled", function(event) {    
  if(event.target.isActive){
    event.target.dataItem.dataContext.dataItem.hide(series.interpolationDuration, 0, 0, ["valueY"]);
  }
  else{
    event.target.dataItem.dataContext.dataItem.show(series.interpolationDuration, 0, ["valueY"]);
  }
})
```

Hope this helps.